# How can I reverse both keys and values in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{a:1,b:2,c:3}`.

How can I print in reverse order:

```
c 3
b 2
a 1
```

Comment: The example you showed accomplishes nothing.. if you would get a value of `c` before the sorting you would get `3`, but after it is the same

Comment: @9769953 this is not what OP requested, the link shows how to invert key/values, not to invert the order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming python 3.6+, for which insertion order in dictionaries is maintained ([guaranteed for python 3.7+](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html)), you can use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

out = dict(reversed(d.items()))

# or
out = {k: d[k] for k in reversed(d)}
```

Output:

```
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

If you want to `print`:

```
for k, v in reversed(d.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

Or:

```
for k in reversed(d):
    print(k, d[k])
```

Output:

```
c 3
b 2
a 1
```